# Is there a way to use Index Match or Vlookup to find data in another workbook?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, formula

I need to find data in one workbook and place it in another workbook.
I need to reference the data using dates going across the row and categories going down the columns. What is the best way to set this up?

This is the closest I have come to solving it but I am getting the error "There is a problem with this formula..."

Matches of C2 and A4 are text criteria to verify it is the right data, they should exist in both workbooks.

```
=INDEX(([Workbook2.xlsx]sheet1!$B$8:$AZ$999);
MATCH(C2;[Workbook2.xlsx]sheet1!$B$7:$ZZ$7;0);
MATCH(A4;[Workbook2.xlsx]sheet1!$A$0:$A$999;0))
```

I expect the data that matches the co-ordinates C2 and A4 in Workbook2 to show up in C2-A4 in Workbook1

Any help in here, any mistake I'm doing or if vlookup or another formula would be better suited to this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Showing the data or examples and expected result may help...

Comment: Use `,` instead of `;`